# Postgres: how to make pgcli stop nagging when running a delete: "You're about to run a destructive command"

Tags: pgcli

I'm using postgres 14

When running a query in pgcli like "delete from mytable;" I get a prompt about it being a destructive command

I put this at the bottom of postgresql.conf but no difference

```
client_min_messages = warning
```

I try running this in the pgcli prompt but I still get the warning

```
SET client_min_messages = 'warning';
```

What gives?

Comment: For better clarity...What is the command you are running for delete?

Comment: "delete from <<tablename>>;"

Comment: `delete from tablename;` without a `WHERE` clause is the same as `TRUNCATE tablename`, which is why you're getting the warning. Running a `delete` without a `WHERE` is a common new SQL user mistake. PostgreSQL is just trying to keep that new user from shooting themselves in the foot. If you mean to delete all rows, use `TRUNCATE` instead, so that it is clear you know what that will do.

Comment: This is not a Postgres message. See [Option for disabling the "destructive command"](https://github.com/dbcli/pgcli/issues/933)

Comment: @klin That was my problem, I didn't know this was a pgcli issue. Much appreciated